# Bound extra ipv6 adress

Tags: ipv6

Im new to Linux, and i'm still learning to setup everything.

I have main adress ipv4, i would like to add extra IPv6 adress to my server.

Im using Ubuntu 20.04.

My provider gave me IPv6 adress: 2a01:0238:4279:3900:e46e:d673:b7c7:db0b

But every tutorial i see something like this: e46e:d673:b7c7:db0b

So i got confused, what i need to bound, wich part. What type of bitrate it is ?

SO i tried: 2a01:0238:4279:3900:e46e:d673:b7c7:db0b::/64

After i restarted server, and nothing worked.

MAybe somebody can provide me with better Tutorial, or explaining ?

I would like to do it by myswlf, to learn it for future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest going through something like [HE.net's IPv6 tutorial](https://ipv6.he.net/certification/), which will give you an introduction.

Comment: If you ISP Strato gave you a single IPv6 address then get yourself another ISP. At the very least, you should have been suppied with a /64 subnet. It sounds like they expect you to run nat over it.